# Multiple dispatch_after can not work well

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

It is easy to delay executing something like this

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

But it will make above code fail to execute if putting another longer delay like

```
double delayInSeconds2 = 3.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    <#code to be executed on the main queue after delay#>
});
```

Why just execute the longer one instead of both ? Or am I totally wrong ?

Comment: It works like this when I tested:  After 2 seconds, top one get executed.  And after another 1,(3-2), second, bottom code get executed.  However bottom code did wait for top code to finish (if top code takes longer than 1 second to finish) before it starts.

Comment: May I understand that it does not work as you expected either ?

Comment: Initially I thought it was a serial queue. But I did another test by setting the delayInSeconds2 = 1.0 and the second code got executed first. So these are independent. My interpretation is that it allows you to schedule multiple dispatch_after but these queues are synchronous in nature.

Answer (score 0):

it is a queue, but the position depend on the future fire time instead of enqueue time.

if second one is 1 second, it will be insert before the first one.

if you want them executed concurrently (time slice for single core or real concurrency for multi-core cpu),  put them on different queue.